# Google admin console and privilege of admin

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-apps

Using `Google App for Work`, the administrator can execute the backup of all user account belonging to its society?

So, my question is: the administrator can use google takeout (https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout) to make a backup of all other account?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A google admin cannot execute takeout on behalf of a user. An admin can transfer the data to another account, however using the data transfer api, located here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/v1/reference/